# Update values of a specified column from one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

Query:

```
select * from emp;
```

Output:

```
ID NAME                        AGE     SALARY ADDRESS
------ -------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
101 Naveen                       28      25000 charminar
102 Vishal                       32      28000 kothapet
180 Manish                       25      18000 Begumpet
120 Sravan                       29      20000 Vidyanagar
106 Mukesh                       26      21000 Vanastalipuram
115 Sankar                       23      15000 Kairtabad
130 Asif                         24      16000 Sultan nagar
142 Deeraj                       27      21500 Lalbazar
```

Query:

```
select * from dept;
```

Output:

```
JOB_ID JOB_TITLE            HIRE_DATE     EMP_ID
------ -------------------- --------- ----------
12254 Software Testing     16-APR-14
13696 Developer            25-MAR-13
13589 Manager              21-JUN-10
13696 developer            26-DEC-13
15395 DBA                  15-APR-12
12254 Software testing     14-NOV-14
13696 Developer            17-FEB-11
15395 DBA                  23-JAN-13
```

I have to copy all the (ID) values from table `EMP` into table `DEPT` (`EMP_ID`).

Comment: How would you do that? What's the relation ?

Comment: This seems like a very odd and possibly totally wrong design - the way you've set it up (`EMP_ID` as FK in table `DEPT`) means: each department can have **at most** ***ONE*** employee ! ..... And how are those two tables connected?? Somehow you must know which employee belongs to which department... (that's the way it *should* be - the `EMP` table should have a `DEPT_ID` foreign key, so that each employee could belong to one department....)

Comment: For your design, the best way is to sit and map the ID one by one coz you cannot join the two tables by any means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other commenters mentioned, you would have to manually establish the link for each EMP_ID:

```
UPDATE dept SET EMP_ID = 101 WHERE JOB_ID = 12254 AND HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('16-APR-14', 'DD-MON-YY');
UPDATE dept SET EMP_ID = 102 WHERE JOB_ID = 13696 AND HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('25-MAR-13', 'DD-MON-YY');
UPDATE dept SET EMP_ID = 180 WHERE JOB_ID = 13589 AND HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('21-JUN-10', 'DD-MON-YY');
UPDATE dept SET EMP_ID = 120 WHERE JOB_ID = 13696 AND HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('26-DEC-13', 'DD-MON-YY');
UPDATE dept SET EMP_ID = 106 WHERE JOB_ID = 15395 AND HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('15-APR-12', 'DD-MON-YY');
UPDATE dept SET EMP_ID = 115 WHERE JOB_ID = 12254 AND HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('14-NOV-14', 'DD-MON-YY');
UPDATE dept SET EMP_ID = 130 WHERE JOB_ID = 13696 AND HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('17-FEB-11', 'DD-MON-YY');
UPDATE dept SET EMP_ID = 142 WHERE JOB_ID = 15395 AND HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('23-JAN-13', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

Just make sure EMP_ID in each statement is the desired one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between emp and dept tables. So there is no way to automatically fill EMP_ID column. you should do it one by one.

The other hint for you is about your design. you can use the below design for storing employee and department data.

[New design for storing department and employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqyXI.png)